# Google Sheets: Dynamic ImportRange Key

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, importrange

I have one sheet with a lot of workbooks inside and every workbook include a lot of `IMPORTRANGE` functions. An example is like this:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1i_lJGwT5345345gfdgdfgd37RCjTn0RlmzZr50C_Wg","Sheet - Name!K3:K999")
```

So this is monthly report and if I copy this sheet I must update all sheet keys in each function every month (this is really time consuming!)

Is there any way to make dynamic key with Script Editor? I try like this:

```
function dynamicKeys() {
  var thisSheetKey = '1543fgdfgdfg23463gdgi7EhmlPkn9j60';
  var dataSheetKey = '';
}
```

And inserting function in cell like this:

```
=IMPORTRANGE('+thisSheetKey+',"FB - Slovenia!K3:K999")
```

But sadly this doesn't work for me.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the key of the sheet using `getId()` like this:

```
function dynamicKeys() {
  var thisSheetKey = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var dataSheetKey = '';
  ... 
  =IMPORTRANGE('+thisSheetKey+',"FB - Slovenia!K3:K999")
}
```